# How to group by email and at the same time get all the columns from the table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

The idea is that when a user asks for an image to be sent to the mail, I need to save his email.

Email is not unique.

Therefore, the user can send 10 images to his mailbox.

And I need to display what image and what email the user sent this image.
That is, I need to get the total number of mail sent.
And how many letters have been sent to a certain email.

I have a table in views.

```
image           email           total
image_id        blah@mail.com (3)
image_id        blah2@mail.ru (2)
```

i use this code

```
photo_booth.send_images.includes(:image).select('distinct on (email) *')
```

but I get a number of unique emails.

How to group by email and at the same time get all the columns from the table?

```
t.string "email"
t.bigint "image_id", null: false
t.bigint "photo_booth_id", null: false
```

Comment: Can you share your model structure?

Comment: I added @Gabbar

Comment: is `Image` a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, since you don't mention the name of your model, I'll assume your model name is EmailImage, ok? Anyway...

You can try the `group_by` method. Something like:

```
photo_booth.send_images.group_by {|res| res.email}
```

will give you a result like:

```
{"blah@mail.com" => [#<EmailImage id: 1, email: "blah@mail.com", image_id: 1>, #<EmailImage id: 2, email: "blah@mail.com", image_id: 2>]}
```

and so on. Notice that the size of the array of the EmailImage object is the total count of repeated emails, so you can use that in the view along with the image_id (taken straight from the object in the array itself) and whatever else you need. Hope it helps! =)